# Is Tails moving to Gentoo?

Tags: debian, gentoo, tails-os

I have a lot of experience with contemporary Linux, but no experience whatsoever with Qubes OS or Tails or the security-focused contemporary distributions. I'm just trying to make sense of what's out there.

The [Wikipedia page for Tails](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tails_(operating_system)) says,

> Tails was first released on 23 June 2009. It is the next iteration of development on Incognito, a Gentoo-based Linux distribution.

The [Wikipedia page for Incognito](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incognito_(operating_system)) says,

> Incognito's developer has stated on the project's homepage that Incognito has been discontinued and recommends Tails as an alternative.

Is Tails then going to stay with Debian/dpkg -- a system I'm used to. Or, are they moving to Gentoo? I'm just confused at,

1. The trajectory of the project.
2. The reasons for entertaining the migration for rebasing atop Gentoo.

Comment: "Tails was first released on 23 June 2009. It is the next iteration of development on Incognito, a Gentoo-based Linux distribution." This statement means "Incognito" which is discontinued is based on Gentoo, not "Tails".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Tails was first released on 23 June 2009. It is the next iteration of development on Incognito, a Gentoo-based Linux distribution.

> Incognito's developer has stated on the project's homepage that Incognito has been discontinued and recommends Tails as an alternative.

Here's the information you can get out of those statements:

1. The project started with Incognito.
2. Incognito is a Gentoo based OS.
3. Incognito has been abandoned and discontinued.
4. Incognito has been replaced by Tails.
5. Tails is the next generation of the project.
6. Tails was initially released June 23, 2009.

Looking further into the the Wikipedia page for Tails states that it uses the DPKG package manager. Check on the information panel located on the right side of the page. So, no, Tails is NOT switching to Gentoo and will remain as is. The Gentoo-based OS was abandoned and discontinued.

Comment: Where do you see this "Tails is the next generation of the project." in the above statement?

Comment: "Tails was first released on 23 June 2009. It is the next iteration of development on Incognito." Iteration and generation are the same thing. So, the statement means that Tails is the replacement for Incognito. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Evan "[Tails] is the next iteration ... on Incognito", so Tails came after Incognito. No reason to see what's in Incognito as the future of Tails.